# Limit of a multiple square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let a sequence be defined $a_1 = 0$ and $a_{n+1} - a_n=4n+3$ for all $n \ge1$ and $n \in N$.

1. Find $a_k$ in terms of $k$.

My approach:-

Since common difference is a linear polynomial, I assumed the $k^{th}$ term to be a quadratic polynomial like $ak^2 + bk+c$.

Now,

$a_{k+1} - a_k=4k+3$

$a(k+1)^2 + b(k+1)+c-ak^2 - bk-c=4k+3$

$2ak + a+b=4k+3$

By comparing coefficients, $ a=2$ and $b=1$

For $c$, we put the value of $a_1$ and get $c=-3$

Hence, $a_k=2k^2+k-3$ or $a_k=(2k+3)(k-1)$

Is there any other method to solve this problem wherein I don't have to assume a polynomial and then find the general term.

2. Find:- $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{a_{4^0n}}+\sqrt{a_{4^1n}}+...+\sqrt{a_{4^{10}n}}}{\sqrt{a_{2^0n}}+\sqrt{a_{2^1n}}+...+\sqrt{a_{2^{10}n}}}$$

I tried to convert it into limit as a sum form but it isn't fruitful. Need hints.

Comment: we can not read you limit term

Comment: but $$4^10=0$$ or do you mean $$4^{10}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry for typo. It is $4^{10}$

Comment: then please correct your term!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think the question is correctly written.

Comment: It is $4^{0}$ continuing till $4^{10}$(subscripts of $a$) in the numerator and $2^{0}$ continuing till $2^{10}$(subscripts of $a$) in the denominator.@Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 1):

For 1.

The equation is a linear recurrence of the first order. Such equations are known to hae a solution wich is the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation (RHS=0) and a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation.

Then

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=0$$ obviously has the general solution $$a_n=C$$ for some constant,

and the first order difference of a polynomial is a polynomial of degree one less and leading coefficient equal to the degree, so we can try

$$a_n=2n^2+C'n$$

and

$$2(n+1)^2+C'(n+1)-2n^2-C'n=4n+2+C'$$ giving $C'=1$.

Hence

$$a_n=2n^2+n+C$$ and there are no other solutions. With $a_1=0$, you indeed select $$C=-3.$$