# Limit Of Square Roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $a(k)=(2k+3)(k-1)$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$. Find:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{a(4^0n)}+\sqrt{a(4^1n)}+\cdots+\sqrt{a(4^{10}n)}}{\sqrt{a(2^0n)}+\sqrt{a(2^1n)}+\cdots+\sqrt{a(2^{10}n)}}$$

I tried to convert it into limit as a sum form but it isn't fruitful. Need hints.

Comment: The answer is $683$

Comment: Hint: For every fixed $k$, $$\sqrt{a_{kn}}\sim\sqrt2\,k\,n$$ when $n\to\infty$. Use this for $k=4^i$ and for $k=2^i$.

Comment: @JanEerland That is correct. Please post a solution. Thanks

Comment: @AmanSharma I checked it with WolframAlpha

Comment: @Did How did you reach this approximation? I didn't get you.

Comment: @AmanSharma Seriously? What is a simple equivalent of $a_{n}$ when $n\to\infty$? Of $a_{3n}$ when $n\to\infty$? Of $a_{kn}$ when $n\to\infty$, for $k$ fixed?

Comment: @Did I am sorry. But I don't know this. I am just a 17 year old and they haven't taught this in India.

Comment: Hence the limit is $$\frac{4^0+4^1+\cdots+4^{10}}{2^0+2^1+\cdots+2^{10}}$$

Comment: @AmanSharma But you are asking the question, right? If you are unable to come with even a simple equivalent of $a_n$ when $n\to\infty$ (a task two orders of magnitude less complicated), **what is the point?**

Comment: @Did, what's with the hostility?  Is it really such a problem that a 17-year-old doesn't have the same mathematical prowess as a research mathematician?

Comment: @tilper Your comment is completely misguided (and more than a little insulting, if you want to know). Try not to project onto others your thoughts/fears/whatever, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Did, I don't mean to be insulting and I'm not projecting anything as my only feeling regarding this is confusion.  Surely you can see how preceding a response to a clarification request with "Seriously?" and then later asking, in bold no less, "what is the point?" to someone who is simply trying to learn something can be interpreted as hostility, especially by strangers over the Internet?  Different people learn things at significantly different paces and the impatience I occasionally see on this site regarding that just confuses me, that's all.

Comment: @tilper Again? The facts are that this question was posted with no context and that, when probed for something notably simpler than their question, the OP declared they had no clue. *This unusual situation is crucial to be aware of* if one wants to concoct a sensible answer (instead of, say, posting a full answer completely useless to the OP). That is, seeing the circumstances, if a sensible answer exists at all... What you feel free to declare publicly as hostility (thanks again for that) is a desire to understand the situation. If you know better, sorry but should this be my concern?

Comment: @tilper Let me add that you might want to meditate the contorsions ThomasGrubb (rightfully, imho) feels obliged to go through to achieve something useful to this OP (who, characteristically, stays silent...).

Comment: Interestingly, this question is [a self-duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2269530/).

Comment: @Did, I already know you weren't being hostile, based on your first response to me. My last question still stands, though.  I wonder, is English not your native language?  Perhaps this and the subtleties of the language is the cause of the miscommunication between us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a bit longer version of @Did's comment above. Note that $$a(k)=2k^2+2k-3=2k^2+o(k^2).$$ (If you haven't seen [little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), it essentially means that all I care about in the asymptotics is the leading term on $k^2$). Thus we have (asymptotically) 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{a(4^0n)}+\dots+\sqrt{a(4^{10}n)}}{\sqrt{a(2^0n)}+\dots+\sqrt{a(2^{10}n})}&\sim\frac{\sqrt{2(4^0n)^2}+\dots+\sqrt{2(4^{10}n)^2}}{\sqrt{2(2^0n)^2}+\dots+\sqrt{2(2^{10}n)^2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}n\left(4^{0}+\dots+4^{10}\right)}{\sqrt{2}n\left(2^{0}+\dots+2^{10}\right)}\\
&=???
\end{align*}

Here is a simpler example to possibly help you see what's going on here. Let's try to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(4n)}{a(2n)}.$$
Just by using the definitions of the sequence we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(4n)}{a(2n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(4n)^2+2(4n)-3}{2(2n)^2+2(2n)-3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{32n^2+8n-3}{8n^2+4n-3}.$$
What do we do from here? Let's multiply both numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{n^2}$. We have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(4n)}{a(2n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{32+\frac{8}{n}-\frac{3}{n^2}}{8+\frac{4}{n}-\frac{3}{n^2}}.$$
Can you see now what this limit should be, and why @Did and I only cared about the leading term in the original example? They work *exactly* the same way.

Comment: Let us see if this is swallowed more easily by the OP than my comments (I see no reason why, but who knows). (+1 anyway.)

Comment: @Did hopefully it will; I'm adding an edit with more explanation on a simpler example which may help

Comment: @Did I think the latter example may shine a little bit of light on things.

Comment: It does, without any doubt. (Unrelated: I took upon myself to change indexes to arguments in the question and in your post, for readability's sake. Hope this does not hurt your authorship's feeling...)